# Getting WebdriverAgent issue on Appium after doing upgrade of iOS from 14.8.1 to 15.1

Tags: ios

Getting the below error when started Appium server on MAC.

> [XCUITest] Executing command 'getScreenshot' [XCUITest] Taking screenshot with WDA [WD Proxy] Matched '/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot' [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/DCB933A9-4D32-4CA3-8BC3-D2555E436DA8/screenshot] with no body [WD Proxy] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"unable to capture screen","message":"A screen capture was made impossible","traceback":""},"sessionId":"DCB933A9-4D32-4CA3-8BC3-D2555E436DA8"} [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'unable to capture screen' to UnableToCaptureScreen [XCUITest] Error getting screenshot: A screen capture was made impossible [XCUITest] Taking screenshot with WDA [WD Proxy] Matched '/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot' [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/DCB933A9-4D32-4CA3-8BC3-D2555E436DA8/screenshot] with no body [WD Proxy] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"unable to capture screen","message":"A screen capture was made impossible","traceback":""},"sessionId":"DCB933A9-4D32-4CA3-8BC3-D2555E436DA8"} [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'unable to capture screen' to UnableToCaptureScreen [XCUITest] Taking screenshot with WDA [WD Proxy] Matched '/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot' [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/DCB933A9-4D32-4CA3-8BC3-D2555E436DA8/screenshot] with no body [WD Proxy] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"unable to capture screen","message":"A screen capture was made impossible","traceback":""},"sessionId":"DCB933A9-4D32-4CA3-8BC3-D2555E436DA8"} [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'unable to capture screen' to UnableToCaptureScreen [MJSONWP (03f67526)] Encountered internal error running command: UnableToCaptureScreen: A screen capture was made impossible [MJSONWP (03f67526)] at errorFromW3CJsonCode (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:780:25) [MJSONWP (03f67526)] at ProxyRequestError.getActualError (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:663:14) [MJSONWP (03f67526)] at JWProxy.command (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:272:19) [MJSONWP (03f67526)] at runMicrotasks () [MJSONWP (03f67526)] at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5) [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/03f67526-fd53-4743-96bd-8cbb9a23eafb/screenshot 500 1062 ms - 123 [HTTP]

Answer (score 0):

What is your Appium version? Can you update Appium to the latest version and try again?
I know this problem has been fixed after 1.22 version.